# Markov Chain - method of generating function -to find nth power

Tags: matrices

P= $\left(\begin {matrix}q&p&0&0\\0&q&p&0\\0&0&q&p\\0&0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)$

We are to find $P^n$  using method of generating function. 
I have understood the steps up to finding the inverse as inv (I-sP) = $\frac{adj(I-sP)}{|I-sP|}$

This matrix works out to

P= $\left(\begin {matrix}(1-sq)^{-1}&sp(q-sq)^{-2}&s^2p^2(1-sq)^{-3}&s^3p^3(1-s)^{-1}(1-sq)^{-3}\\0&(1-sq)^{-1}&sp(1-sq)^2&s^2p^2(1-s)^{-1}(1-sq)^{-2}\\0&0&(1-sq)^{-1}&sp(1-s)^{-1}(1-sq)^{-1}\\0&0&0&(1-s)^{-1}\end{matrix}\right)$

I have not understood the next step in the textbook which says now collect coefficients of $s^n$ by expanding each element of $(I-sP)^{-1}$ in powers of s to get the matrix. The first row of this matrix is

$\left(\begin{matrix} q^n&& npq^{n-1}&&\frac{n(n-1)p^2q^{n-2}}{2}&&p^3(1+3q+6q^2+.......)\end{matrix}\right)$

Request guide as to how is this done for the first row of the matrix. I will work out the rest based on this

Comment: did you really intend the 4,4 entry in the original matrix to be $1$ rather than $q?$

Comment: Yes, I have cross checked. The 4,4 entry in original matrix P is 1 and not q

Comment: What is the name of your textbook? The fourth entry in that row cannot be correct, as it doesn't depend on $n$.